# How to apply filter in a list with Checkbox in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list that renders some products, these products are divided into some categories. Some products may have more than one category.

I am trying to apply a filter with these categories through checkboxes. When the user checks the checkbox, the list must be updated with the selected category.

[image]

I'm still a beginner in `Redux` and I don't know how to communicate between the components to update the list. I said communication between components because my list of categories is in the `Drawer` Component, and my list of products is in the `Card` component.

I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-k69qu?file=/src/App.js) because has a lot of files

Here I'm rendering my list of products:

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import CardItem from '../CardItem';
import Pagination from '../Pagination';
import Search from '../Search';
import { useStyles } from './styles';

const Card = (props) => {
  const { activeFilter } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.perfume.collections);
  const [searchPerfume, setSearchPerfume] = useState('');
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [perfumesPerPage, setPerfumesPerPage] = useState(3);

  console.log('activeFilter: ', activeFilter);

  const filteredPerfumes = useMemo(() => {
    return data.filter((perfume) =>
      perfume.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPerfume.toLowerCase())
    );
  }, [data, searchPerfume]);

  const currentPerfumes = filteredPerfumes.slice(
    (currentPage - 1) * perfumesPerPage,
    currentPage * perfumesPerPage
  );
  const pages = Math.ceil(filteredPerfumes.length / perfumesPerPage);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentPage > pages) {
      setCurrentPage(1);
    }
  }, [currentPage, pages]);

  const pageNumbers = Array(pages)
    .fill(null)
    .map((val, index) => index + 1);

  const handleClick = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        data-testid="input-filter-id"
        setSearchPerfume={setSearchPerfume}
      />
      {currentPerfumes
        .filter((perfume) => {
          return (
            perfume.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchPerfume.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          );
        })
        .map((item) => (
          <CardItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      <Pagination
        pageNumbers={pageNumbers}
        handleClick={handleClick}
        currentPage={currentPage}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Here I'm rendering my list of categories:

```js
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { useStyles } from './styles';

const DrawerComponent = (props) => {
  const { activeFilter, setActiveFilter } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.perfume.collections);

  const handleChange = (text) => (event) => {
    setActiveFilter((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      value: event.target.checked,
      text,
    }));
  };

  const allCategories = data
    .reduce((p, c) => [...p, ...c.categories], [])
    .filter((elem, index, self) => index === self.indexOf(elem));

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <List className={classes.list}>
        {allCategories.sort().map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem className={classes.itemList} button key={text}>
            <Checkbox onChange={handleChange(text)} />
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DrawerComponent;
```

Do you know how I can apply this filter to my list?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### State Contol

Generally when you need to communicate between components, the solution is [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).  Meaning that the state should be controlled by a common ancestor.

Instead of having this in your `DrawerComponent`:

```
const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = React.useState([]);
```

Move that hook up to your `PerfumeStore` and pass `activeFilter` and `setActiveFilter` as props to `DrawerComponent`.

You need to add an `onChange` function to the `Checkbox` components in `DrawerComponent` which adds or removes the category by calling `setActiveFilter`.

So now you need to apply the `activeFilter` to your list of perfumes, which is determined in `Card`.  You could move all of that filtering up to `PerfumeStore`, but to keep it simple let's pass `activeFilter` down as a prop to `Card` (it just needs to read but not write the filter, so we don't pass down `setActiveFilter`).  Now the `Card` component has the information that it needs to filter the items based on the selected categories.

### Redux Selectors

Everything so far has just had to do with react and the fact that you are using redux hasn't come into play at all.  The way that you would incorporate redux principles, if you wanted to, is do define some of the filtering and mapping logic outside of your components as selector functions of `state` and other arguments.  Then instead of calling `useSelector` to get a huge chunk of state which you process inside the component, you can call `useSelector` with a selector that gets just the data which you need.

An obvious place to do this is in `DrawerComponent`, where you are getting the category list.  Make a selector function `getPerfumeCategories` which takes the `state` and returns the categories.  Then in your component, you call `const allCategories = useSelector(getPerfumeCategories);`

Now all that this component is responsible for is rendering the categories.  It is no longer responsible for storing the selections (we've already moved the `useState` out) or for finding the categories from the state.  This is good!  You can read up on principles like the Single Responsibility Principle, Separation of Concerns, Logic vs. Presentation components, etc. if you want a deeper understanding of why this is good.

In `Card` you could use a selector that gets an already-filtered list of perfumes. But in this case a `getCurrentPagePerfumes` function would take a lot of different arguments so it's kind of messy.

### Edit: Filtering

You've asked for help with how to apply the value of `activeFilter` to filter the perfumes which are shown in your list.

Multiple categories can be selected at once, so `activeFilter` needs to identify **all** of the actively selected categories.  I first suggested an array of names, but removing items from an array (without mutation) is more complicated than assigning values to objects.

So then I thought about having an object where the keys are the category names and the values are a `boolean` true/false of whether the category is checked.  This makes `handleChange` really simple because we can update the value for that key to the value of `event.target.checked`.

```
  const handleChange = (text) => (event) => {
    setActiveFilter((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [text]: event.target.checked,
    }));
  };
```

- `...prev` says "keep everything the same except the key that I am changing".
- `[text]` says "the key I am updating is the variable `text`, not the literal key 'text'"
- `event.target.checked` is the boolean of whether this category is checked.

We could set an initial state for `activeFilter` which includes a key for every category and all the values are `false` (ie. nothing selected).  Or we could allow for the object to be incomplete with the assumption that if it key isn't included, then it isn't checked.  Let's do that.

So now our `activeFilter` looks something like: `{Floral: true, Floriental: false, Fresh: true}` where some are `true`, some are `false`, and lots are missing and therefore assumed to be `false`.

We need to figure out how to filter the displayed perfumes based on the value of `activeFilter`.  Let's start by writing a function that determines whether one perfume is eligible to be shown, and then we can use that as a callback of array.filter() on an array of perfumes.  We want a perfume to be included if **any** of its categories are checked (unless you want it to match all the checked categories?).  That looks like:

```
    perfume.categories.some( 
      category => activeFilter[category] === true
    );
```

Where [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) loops through the categories and returns `true` if our callback is `true` for any category.

I added this to your `filteredPerfumes` memo and added `activeFilter` as a dependency so that it will re-filter when the checkboxes change.

```
  const filteredPerfumes = useMemo(() => {
    return data.filter((perfume) =>
      perfume.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPerfume.toLowerCase())
      && perfume.categories.some( 
        category => activeFilter[category] === true
      )
    );
  }, [data, searchPerfume, activeFilter]);
```

That works, except that nothing shows when no categories are checked -- whoops!  So we want to add a special case that says "all perfumes pass the category filter if no categories are checked."  To do that, we need to know if there are checked categories or not.  There's a lot of ways to do that, but here's one:

```
const hasCategoryFilter = Object.values(activeFilter).includes(true);
```

We look at all of the values in the `activeFilter` object and see if it includes any which are `true`.

Now we need to use this value to only filter based on categories when it's `true`. I'll pull our previous logic into a function and add an `if` statement (note: the boolean operator `||` is shorter to use, but I think the `if` is more readable).

```
    const matchesCategories = (perfume) => {
      if ( hasCategoryFilter ) {
        return perfume.categories.some( 
          category => activeFilter[category] === true
        );
      } else return true;
    }
```

Sidenote: we have two independent filters, one for search and one for category, so we could call `data.filter` once and check for both conditions at once or twice and check each condition separately.  It does not matter which you do.

The final filter is:

```
  const filteredPerfumes = useMemo(() => {
    const hasCategoryFilter = Object.values(activeFilter).includes(true);

    const matchesCategories = (perfume) => {
      if ( hasCategoryFilter ) {
        return perfume.categories.some( 
          category => activeFilter[category] === true
        );
      } else return true;
    }

    return data.filter((perfume) =>
      perfume.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPerfume.toLowerCase())
    ).filter( matchesCategories );
    
  }, [data, searchPerfume, activeFilter]);
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-forked-71gng?file=/src/features/components/Card/Card.jsx)

Comment: Hii Linda, First of all thank you very much for your help, what you sent gave me guidance on what to do. I updated my question, now I am able to get the filter value and know if it is true or false. But I'm not able to apply this filter to my list, do you know how I can do that? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: `activeFilter` needs to be an array since there are multiple categories checked. Then you need to compare the selected categories to the categories of the perfumes. I'll play around with the code.

Comment: Or you could have a keyed object with each of the categories and whether they are checked or not.

Comment: Hii Linda, I will try to transform `activeFilter` into an array with the selected categories and then try to compare them with `perfumes`.

Comment: I was just thinking about how it's kind of a pain in the ass to add and remove items from an array (it's easier if you are updating true/false values in a keyed object) and I remembered that you can use a [Multiple Select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) in material UI rather than handling individual checkboxes.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer.  I didn't change that much code but I wrote a damn novel about it lol.

Comment: Hey Linda, that was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your time, attention and explanation.